# How can I get the jruby version at runtime?

Tags: runtime, version, jruby

I need to get the jruby version for logging & debugging purposes.

I tried looking around `JRuby.runtime` for a `version` method, but I didn't find anything useful.

I also thought about using `%x{jruby -v}`. It works in most cases, except that there is always the possibility that more than one jruby version are installed, and I want to get the version of the currently running interpreter.

Did I miss something? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the global constant JRUBY_VERSION. This is a brother of VERSION, RUBY_ENGINE (not available under 1.8.x), RUBY_PLATFORM, etc.

Comment: Nice, though not as detailed as jruby -v.

Comment: For more details, you can check the RUBY_DESCRIPTION constant